# Switching is not happening when i am using selenium webdriver

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Consider my situation:

There is three web pages let us name it as A,B,C

At First I am launching web page 'A' by using selenium in java

Link is present in the webpage 'A'. When I click that link it moves to link 'B'.

I am doing some basic operations and then I need to close that window.

So that My webpage 'C' will be open and I have switch  to it and do some operations.

I have done upto closing the webpage 'B'. so that webpage 'C' is opened.
But I failed to switching to it.

For checking the code I have tried to switch to webpage 'A'. It's switching to webpage 'A'
but not switching to webpage 'C'

Please Suggest the solution ASAP

((JavaScriptExecutor)driver). executeScript("window.close();");

```
Set<String> winHandleBefore =        driver.getWindowHandles();
For(string title:winHandleBefore){
 Driver.switchto().window(title);
               if(driver.gettitle().contains( winHandleBefore)){
 driver.manage().maximize();
```

}
}

This is the code I have used

Comment: Probably it is something you are doing wrong in code. Can you share that as well?

Comment: I am looking for solution in selenium java . I have close the window  by two ways

1)By using javaScriptExecutor
2)By using driver.close();

I think  the windowhandle is not available after when i am closing the window.

Comment: ((JavaScriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("window.close();");

 String winHandleBefore = driver.getWindowHandle();

        for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){

            driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);

        }

Comment: (Without knowing the code and the sites) What if you try like 
for(String winHandle : driver.getWindowHandles()){ if (!winHandle.equals(winHandleBefore) {driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);}
? 
Maybe there is a switch, just fast, since you iterate through all handles, including the current one.

Comment: I am not sure. But I will update the details  as soon as possible

Comment: Please edit your original post with your code, do not put in the comments.

Comment: Please suggest a solution ASAP

Answer (score -1):

Why are you closing the window using javascript?

If I had to guess from the very limited code example you have given, I'd say that would be where you are going wrong.  Closing a browser window with anything other than driver.quit() or driver.close() can result in instability.

Comment: We also tried with driver.close() but the result is same the switching is not happened. But driver.quit will shutdown the selenium so we didn't use that

Comment: closing the browser without shutting down your driver is a terrible idea.  I cannot think of a single use case where that cannot be done with more stability by just simply calling driver.quit() and then re-creating the driver.